# PHP $_GET works but $_POST echos blank

Tags: php, ajax, post, get

Here is the JavaScript Ajax and PHP that correctly return the string "Test" with GET:

```
    var xmlhttp;
if (window.XMLHttpRequest){
    xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
}
else{
    xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
}
xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function(){
    if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200){
        document.getElementById("content").innerHTML=xmlhttp.responseText;
    }
}
xmlhttp.open("GET","selector.php?storyId=Test",true);
xmlhttp.send();
```

and the PHP:

```
<?php
$storyId=$_GET['storyId'];
echo $storyId;
?>
```

But when using POST, as follows, it echos blank (but it does echo)

```
<?php
$storyId=$_POST['storyId'];
echo $storyId;
?>
```

And the last two altered lines of JavaScript:

```
xmlhttp.open("POST","selector.php",true);
xmlhttp.send("storyId=Test");
```

Why does this happen?

Answer (score 3):

Try adding a header to it when it by adding this in between `open()` and `send()`:

```
xmlhttp.setRequestHeader("Content-type","application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
```

Comment: It Works! You're stacked bro.